# How to justify using a prediction model with higher RMSE (cv=10)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am working on a prediction model. To get to the best possible model, I am using cross_val_score for comparison among different models with CV=10 and the RMSE, I am getting is as follows:

```
                                       Lasso      SVR        NuSVR  GradientBoostingRegressor   RandomForestRegressor
Modeling Methods(15 fact and FR)    0.748253    0.779394    0.776631    0.796389                  0.792362
```

From this, it is clear that the best model based upon RMSE is Lasso, but I try to predict the unseen data with this, it only gives a single number like 31.07 for every case. While GradientBoostingRegressor, gives best predictions out of all the models.

Now I am wondering how to justify taking GradientBoostingRegressor model, while it has higher RMSE?

My sample unseen data with prediction from Lasso

```
 Disaster Number_left       county_state  Total Destroyed  pred_TD_actual  \
0          279-17          Camden_MO                8       31.043349   
1          279-17            Cole_MO               13       31.043349   
2          279-17            Dent_MO                3       31.043349
```

Comment: What do you mean by "single number like 31.07"? How many data points you have in the unseen data?

Comment: i have 29 data points in unseen data and for every data point lasso gives 31.07 as prediction, even after fine tuning its parameter

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your dada? Also, did you check what are the nonzero coefficients of Lasso?

Comment: I have added the unseen data and have not checked the nonzero coefficients

Comment: I would suggest to check them. If you get exactly the same output for every data point, then maybe all of them (or all except of very few) are 0, and the features on which they are not 0 are identical.

Comment: Yes all the coefficients are zero, how to go about it?

Comment: Decrease the value of alpha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StratifiedKFold did the trick for me i.e. shuffling the data before applying Cross validation. Now, the model with the least cv scores also gives good predictions, as desired